# How i get by NFC-Scanning with Flutter/Android the same Uid like when i scanning with iOS?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, nfc

When i scan with my iOS app a NFC-Tag i get this result:

04ea1b72835c80

i think this is the Uid.

Now i program with Flutter and the NFC-Manager package a NFC-Reader for Android.
Now when i scan the same NFC Tag i get this Information:

{nfca: {identifier: [4, 234, 27, 114, 131, 92, 128], atqa: [68, 0], maxTransceiveLength: 253, sak: 0, timeout: 618}, mifareultralight: {identifier: [4, 234, 27, 114, 131, 92, 128], maxTransceiveLength: 253, timeout: 618, type: 2}, ndef: {identifier: [4, 234, 27, 114, 131, 92, 128], isWritable: true, maxSize: 492, canMakeReadOnly: true, cachedMessage: null, type: org.nfcforum.ndef.type2}}

i use this code in flutter:

```
  void _tagRead() {
    NfcManager.instance.startSession(onDiscovered: (NfcTag tag) async {
      var mytag = tag.data;
      result.value = tag.data ;
      NfcManager.instance.stopSession();
   });
  }
```

i tried to parse the identifier in different ways but i didn´t get the same result how from iOS.

Anyone know the right way?

Comment: Which package are you using?

Comment: package:nfc_manager/nfc_manager.dart

Answer (score 2):

This

```
  void _tagRead() {
    NfcManager.instance.startSession(onDiscovered: (NfcTag tag) async {
    var mytag = tag.data;
    result.value = tag.data ;
    NfcManager.instance.stopSession();
  });
 }
```

change to

```
  void _tagRead() {
    NfcManager.instance.startSession(onDiscovered: (NfcTag tag) async {
    var mytag = tag.data["mifareultralight"]["identifier"].map((e) => e.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')).join(''); ;

    result.value = mytag ;
 
    NfcManager.instance.stopSession();
  });
}
```

and i got 04ea1b72835c80

Comment: how did you utilize Uid to extract the customer information like name